# Creating open content area and restricted content area

Tags: plugin-development, e-commerce

I'd like to create a site that has two separate areas of content. One for members with a payment system and another one for regular viewers that gives teasers so that they would want to read more and engage in the proprietary content.

Is this something that WordPress is capable of or should I search for more complex content management systems for solution? How can I do that?

Comment: Do you just want WP to handle the login for you? That's possible.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this something that WordPress is capable of or should I search for
>   more complex content management systems for solution?

The two sections should be easy. Create a [Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Types) for either your free or your paid content. It would be easy to restrict the one or the other by checking ([is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)) to see if a user is logged in before displaying content.

WordPress does not have a built is payment system but there are numerous plugins for many of the third party processing companies.

Answer (score 0):

There is a variety of plugins to achieve this, two of the best being:
http://www.s2member.com/ and http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/membership/

Answer (score 0):

I prefer S2Member for this type of tasks. It's a WordPress plugin.
It supports monthly payment for membership. It manages users billing directly from your paypal account. Provide free and premium version. Check it here: http://s2member.com/

If you need more features and flexibility with user management, then I would recommend aMember. You can also use it along with WordPress. Check here: www.amember.com